# Selenium IDE: Find correct Xpath element based on line

Tags: xpath, selenium

I'm using Selenium IDE and I have this sales information on a web page (example: http://s23.postimg.org/6vwlkqm57/image.jpg) that I need to store some info in variables. One of the info that I need to store is the Country letters (in this example, I need to store the letters LV in a variable).

I'm currently using this command:

Command: **storeText** || Target: **//div[@id='content-main']/form[2]/table[4]/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]** || Value: **Country**

The problem is: This Country information is not always on the 9th line (tr[9]) like in this example, sometimes it is in the 10th line.

My question is: Is there a way to, first find the correct line and then store the country letters?

HERE IS THE SOURCE HTML -- http://txtup.co/VPZR

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: without the html, it's very difficult to help you.

Comment: Sorry, the HTML contains sensitive information from my company, they did not allow me to post the HTML :( ... I want to know if there's a way to use something like "contains" to find the right line ... but I'll try to remove the sensitive info from the HTML an upload it on a txt file.

Comment: in xpath, it's `E[contains(@attr, 'contains')]` (replace `@attr` with `text()` if you want to match on text.)

Comment: wow, your dev team really screwed you over.. tell them they need to adopt a new process to attach id's to their crap

Comment: On the plain text of this HTML, there's business email addresses of employees here, it's a HTML from the intranet, that's why I had to remove some things there.

Comment: that's perfectly fine.. it's exactly what we needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This xpath should fix your problem -

```
//div[@id='content-main']/form[2]/table[4]//tr[contains(text(), 'Country')]/td[2]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still can't find it :(, I get this error: [error] locator not found: //div[@id='content-main']/form[2]/table[4]/tbody/tr[contains(text(),'Country')]/td[2] -- I uploaded the HTML source on my question, maybe it helps

Comment: Thanks @sircapsalot, I just added td[1] on your code before the "contains" and it worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work, thanks for everyone that helped me, I used this sintax:

//div[@id='content-main']/form[2]/table[4]/tbody/tr[td[1][contains(text(), 'Country')]]/td[2]